# Reason for thread to enter blocked state when execution is in non synchronized section

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads running: main and child thread. The activities they do are:

1. Child thread counts the sum of 1 to 100.
2. Main thread prints the total sum once it's calculated by child (so I used `wait` and `notify`). Also it outputs the child thread status.

So below is the code part.

```
class MainThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.setName("Child thread: ");
        b.start();

        synchronized(b) {
            System.out.print("\nwaiting for b to complete\n");

            b.wait();

            System.out.print("\nno more wait .........................\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                System.out.print("\n" + b.getName() + "'s state:" + b.getState());
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        System.out.print("\n" + b.getName() + "state:" + b.getState());
        System.out.print("\ntotal in " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "is :" + b.total);
    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread {

    int total;

    public  void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                total += i;
            System.out.println(this.getName() + "finished sum, lets notify other objects");

            notify();
            System.out.println(this.getName() + " done with notify and sync block\n");
        }

        System.out.println(this.getName() + " : entered non critical section"); 
        for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
            System.out.print("Hi ");
        }
    }
}
```

1. Child finished its synchronized block and notified main thread. and even it's started non synced part which is nothing but printing `"Hi "` in loop.
2. Now main thread after notified, resumed its work and prints child's status.

But here is my observation: while executing the `"Hi "` (for loop which is in non sync block), sometimes child's status is `RUNNABLE` and most of the times it's `BLOCKED`. For example:

```
Child thread: 's state:RUNNABLE Hi Hi Hi 

Child thread: 's state:BLOCKED Hi Hi Hi Hi
```

What caused the child thread to enter in `BLOCKED` state when executing its non-synced block?

Answer (score 4):

Two threads cannot print to the same device at the same time. If they try, one of them will have to be blocked.

Comment: But even when i commented both SOP statements (printing non cs and "HI" printing), still i observed child thread state is "BLOCKED" most of the times. i.e. Just a loop with 100 times with out any print statements in non synchronized part of the code also got blocked

Comment: It's hard to comment on code we can't see. What was the code actually doing? A loop to count to 100 and do nothing would be instantaneous and maybe even optimized out. Likely it hit something that is syncronized -- possibly even garbage collection, memory allocation, or any of a dozen other things.

Answer (score 0):

The two threads do not synchronize each other on ThreadB but on the `System.out` Printstream's write method, which has a synchronized block so only one thread can write to the stream at a time.

```
public void write(int b) {
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
            ensureOpen();
            out.write(b);
            if ((b == '\n') && autoFlush)
                out.flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: But even when i commented both SOP statements (printing non cs and "HI" printing),  still i observed child thread state is "BLOCKED" most of the times. i.e. Just a loop with 100 times with out any print statements in non synchronized part of the code also got blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question.  Are you saying that the child thread *hangs*?  (i.e., are you saying that it becomes BLOCKED forever?)  If so, that's probably a *lost notification*.

Your program contains a data race.  After the main thread calls `b.start()` the two threads race to synchronize on the new `ThreadB` object.  If the `ThreadB` thread wins the race, it will enter the synchronized block, count up to 100, call `this.notify()` and then exit.

As soon as the `ThreadB` thread exits the `synchronized` block, then the `MainThread` thread is able to enter its `synchronized` block, and call `b.wait()`.  The `b.wait()` call will never return because there's no other thread that will ever call `b.notify()`:  The `ThreadB` thread is already done and gone by that point.

A call to `b.notify()` does not do *anything at all* if there is no other thread that is already waiting.  The object, `b`, does not remember that it was notified.

---

The `wait()` and `notify()` methods are low level primitives that were meant to be used in a very specific way.  See the Oracle [Guarded Blocks Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) for more info.

Comment: It is not completely blocked for ever. Once it finishes its for loop thread is getting terminated. My only concern is while this for loop in execution, thread state printed as Blocked.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes `ThreadB` runs faster than **main thread** and gets synchronized (this) first. In this case it should work by your scenario. But sometimes main thread runs in  synchronized(b) faster. And then `ThreadB` gets blocked by main thread that, in turn, waits for notification from b. 
Try to remove synchronized block from main thread and relay only on `b.wait()`.

Comment: This is not quite correct! b.wait() is giving up the monitor while waiting. Thus, no deadlock will occur.